# VBA Insert rows at certain point in data

Tags: vba, excel

I have this pivot table I am inserting above my data. The data can be different lengths and so the pivot table and be different lengths. So what I do is put the data a little ways down on the sheet starting at say maybe row 30. Then I insert my pivot table up top. What I do next is I then have some code to delete all of the blank rows in between my data and the pivot table.

```
sub foo()
    dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z50")
    rows = r.rows.Count
    For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

This code will delete all of the blank rows and seems to work correctly. Since that puts everything together, what I want to do then is just put 2 blank rows in between my pivot table and my data but I don't know how to figure out where my pivot table ends or where my data begins.

[image]

So I want it to look like that ^^^^ , but right now Row 7 and 8 are not there and my data is pushed up onto my pivot table. Any help is appreciated please!

I was thinking someone like using `Rows.Count + 1` or something to find where the pivot table ends. But I don't know how it would determine that since there is data in the row right after. SO maybe I need to find when there is data starting in say Column A then Insert the rows right before that. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Get your pivot table area and then next 2 rows from there.  `Set pvt = Sheet4.PivotTables(1)
    
    MsgBox pvt.TableRange1.Offset(pvt.TableRange1.Rows.Count).Resize(2).Address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along those lines:

```
Public Sub Answer()
    Dim dataTopRowIndex As Integer
    Dim ptBottomRowIndex As Integer

    With ActiveSheet 'Note: use your worksheet's CodeName here instead, e.g. With Sheet1 (Active[anything], Activate, Select, Selection: evil).
        dataTopRowIndex = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        With .PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange1 'Replace PivotTable1 by your PT's name.
            ptBottomRowIndex = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
        End With

        If (dataTopRowIndex - ptBottomRowIndex - 1) > 2 Then
            .Range(.Rows(ptBottomRowIndex + 1), .Rows(dataTopRowIndex - 3)).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks great. I am not too sure why it works. I don't understand what the .row + .rows.Count - 1 does and it wouldnt tell me each variable as I step through it. I see how the first part works, getting the top row index, but i didn't get the second part. But this will work great as long as I don't run my other code first, because this will delete the rows but not put them back in. This will also only work well if there are no blank rows in my data, which there should not be but just letting other people know. It will work if there are blank rows but it will keep the blank rows also. Thanks!

Comment: The `.Row + .Rows.Count - 1` part calculates where the PT's last row is. The qualifier (object in the parent With block) is TableRange1, which covers the whole PT (except for the eventual page fields). So `.Row` is TableRange1's first row, and `.Rows.Count` is TableRange1's rows count.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh ok thank you. yeah I could figure what the count probably was but I wasn't sure what the just `.Row` was. Alright so that makes sense. I have not really done much with pivottables. I have some code that I use to make them but I just copy and paste that when I need to do it again. Thank you for your help this will prove useful in the future.